# Remove the Nullable items from list in join

Tags: c#, listview, entity-framework-core

I am joining multiple tables in the entity framework core

here is the code below(the following code is just for demonstration but it follows the same structure as my current code)

```
   var repor1 = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<repor1>().AsNoTracking();
   var repor2 = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<repor2>().AsNoTracking();
   var repor3 = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<repor3>().AsNoTracking();
   var repor4 = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<repor4>().AsNoTracking();

  var query =
            from rp1 in repor1
            join rp2 in repor2 on rp1.report1Id equals rp2.report1Id
            join rp3 in repor3 on rp2.report2Id equals rp3.report2Id
            join rp4 in repor4 on rp3.report3Id equals rp4.report3Id 
            into report4Default
            current in report4Default.DefaultIfEmpty()
            
            and so on..
          
            select new { rp1,rp2,rp3,rp4 };
```

I have used left join.

Now I am getting results as well using the above query.

But in the case of **rp4** there are **some nullable items** as well **due to left join**.

I want to remove those nullable items before I used this object.

I don't want to change the join. Want to remove null values from rp4.
here I want to remove all the items which are null from rp4.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Small guess: You should add `where rp1 != null && rp2 != null` in the linq query. You could replace `and so on..` for that

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestions. Actually, I have used left join in the query and want to remove those null values from rp1 list items. I have updated the query.

Comment: so I want to remove rp4 items which are null only. I am using this rp4 object for further processing.

Comment: You did not use left join everywhere. The first two joins are inner join. I don't see how this will return anything for non-existing `rp1` etc. Also, it doesn't help that the syntax isn't correct, it makes the question unclear.

Comment: Hi @Gret.. and what about the 3rd join. Doesn't it look like to you the left join.

Comment: Yes, as I said, but its the inner joins that matter. I really can't grab what you're trying to achieve here. Fix the syntax, show sample data and desired output, i.e. a [mre]. This query can never return "items which are null from rp1 or rp2".

Comment: @Gret there was a typo mistake.. I also updated my question. Also, this query mimics my actual query.

Comment: @VirenderThakur `where rp4 != null`? I still don't understand what makes this so hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235477/discussion-between-virender-thakur-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: @GertArnold bleh, thanks. Got screwed over by the SE API not checking for conflicts again :')

Comment: So you want to change a query result without changing the query. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

probably just better to remove nulls originally

```
var report1 = report1.Where(r => r.report1Id != null);
```

if the `report1Id` fields are nullable, then use `r.report1Id.HasValue`

Comment: rp4 has some values after join and it returns me the item. I want then from rp4 to remove nullable items to use it further.